# oracle 19 compatibility with powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: oracle11g

I have a question. We are about to migrate from Oracle 11 to Oracle 19, but we have the main system of the company in PowerBuilder 12.5.
Will you know if power builder 12.5 is compatible with oracle19?
Thank you very much in advance for your answers and support.

Will you know if power builder 12.5 is compatible with oracle19?

Comment: This should be found in PowerBuilder documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- You can let Oracle 19c to be backwards compatible:

  ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER Parameter
  Set the minimum authentication protocol allowed when
  connecting to Oracle Database instances with password version.
  Check the password version with dba_users table with column password_versions.
- Other option would be replace `oci.dll` (and its dependents) on client's side. Oracle C OCI API is usually very backward compatible.